# batch script stops after winrs command

Tags: cmd, command, winrs

```
@(setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    echo off
    set "Node1=Node1"
    set "Node2=Node2"
    set "Node3=Node3"
    set "Cluster=Cluster1"
    set LOGFILE=C:\BatchLog.log
)

CALL:Main >> %LOGFILE% 2>&1

( ENDLOCAL
  CALL :END
  EXIT /B 0


)

:Main
    CALL :Connect_Remote "%Node3%"

    CALL :Print_NodeStatus

GOTO :EOF


:Connect_Remote
start winrs  -r:%~1 cmd
TIMEOUT /T 5
ECHO Login  to %COMPUTERNAME%
ECHO %DATE% %TIME%
ECHO.
ECHO %DATE% %TIME%
ECHO.
GOTO :EOF

:Print_NodeStatus
ECHO ***CURRENT STATUS OF SERVERS***
cluster.exe WINCLU01 node  /status
ECHO %DATE% %TIME%
ECHO.
GOTO :EOF

:Error
EXIT /B 0 %ERRORLEVEL%
GOTO :EOF
```

I have a batch script that needs to run on another server locally **( 4th server)** but same VLAN. It needs to check if the servers **(node1, node2, and node 3)** in the cluster is UP and running.
I have created subclass in my script:

**:Connect_Remote**
and
**:Print_NodeStatus**

After this part is run: *start winrs  -r:%~1 cmd*

It doesn't continue to **:Print_NodeStatus**

What am I missing?

Comment: @KJ FYI I know that it requires USERNAME and password. However it works without it.

Comment: I need in my script that once it is connected remotely to the server using:
 start winrs  -r:"server" cmd

it will be able to run script on the remote CMD.

Comment: @KJ how will you be able to accomplish this?
I need in my script that once it is connected remotely to the server using: start winrs -r:"server" cmd it will be able to run script on the remote CMD.

Comment: I cannot find anything that prevents the routine `:Print_NodeStatus` from running. Why are you using `start` to run `winrs`? Have you tried without `start`?